# HikariPool-1 - Connection marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(-99999)

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp, db2-400

```
HikariPool-1 - Connection marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(-99999)
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communication link failure. (Read timed out)
```

I kept getting this problem, when creating a table with data, which was about 6million records. On ACS, an sql developer, it took around 1½ minute.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found out that default connection validation (`spring.datasource.hikari.validationTimeout`) was set to 5000 (5 seconds).
This lead to hikari, not being able to validate the connection, because it was busy for long time.
Solution was setting this property to a high enough number (i set it to 5minutes - 300000)

Comment: Thanks alot, it took 30 mins to resolve. At last got your solution, it helped me.

Comment: Complementing the answer, in order to do what @Anders suggested you just need to add this key `spring.datasource.hikari.validationTimeout=300000` to your application properties file

Comment: Simple and precise answer. Thanks man